# Azure Active Directory SSO in ASP.NET MVC 5 intermittently failing

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have implemented SSO through AAD in my ASP.NET MVC application.
The following is my SignIn method and the callback.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public void SignIn(int cid)
{
    string callbackUrl = Url.Action("Callback", "AADSignIn", new { cid }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    }
    else
        RedirectToAction("Index", "Catalog");
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Callback(int cid)
{
    ClaimsPrincipal user = User as ClaimsPrincipal;
    var email = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "email" || x.Type == "upn" || x.Type == "preferred_username")?.Value;
    var principal = _aadSignInService.GetPrincipal(email, cid);

    //sometimes principal == null
    //this happens when User is GenericPrincipal and not ClaimsPrincipal
```

The implementation works every time on other environments. Within Azure, my app is registered the same for all environments, as far as I can tell.

I did notice some differences when tracing http calls between successful sign-ons and ones that fail. Here is the callback for the successful sign-on, run on a staging environment.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Location: [address of callback]
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Set-Cookie: OpenIdConnect.nonce.[more here]=; path=/; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: .AspNet.Cookies=[more here]; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Thu, 20 Jan 2022 19:33:46 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

And here is the failed callback

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Location: [address of callback]
Server: 
X-StackifyID: [stackify runs on production]
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-POWERED-BY: 
X-ASPNET-VERSION: 
Date: Thu, 20 Jan 2022 19:31:16 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

As you can see, there are no cookies on the one that is failing.
I'm not sure what more to check.